# Why is output bundle built with Webpack and Gulp so big (>1.9Mb)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, ecmascript-6, webpack

I am using `webpack` and `gulp` via `node`/`npm` to build and uglify browser application. The problem is that the output app.js is about 1.9Mb. It seems far too big and suggests I'm probably missing something.

I start the build process using `gulp build --release`

This is my gulp file:

```
import path from 'path';
import cp from 'child_process';
import gulp from 'gulp';
import gulpLoadPlugins from 'gulp-load-plugins';
import del from 'del';
import mkdirp from 'mkdirp';
import runSequence from 'run-sequence';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import minimist from 'minimist';

const $ = gulpLoadPlugins();
const argv = minimist(process.argv.slice(2));
const src = Object.create(null);

let watch = false;
let browserSync;

// The default task
gulp.task('default', ['sync']);

// Clean output directory
gulp.task('clean', cb => {
  del(['.tmp', 'build/*', '!build/.git'], {dot: true}, () => {
    mkdirp('build/public', cb);
  });
});

// Static files
gulp.task('assets', () => {
  src.assets = 'src/public/**';
  return gulp.src(src.assets)
    .pipe($.changed('build/public'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/public'))
    .pipe($.size({title: 'assets'}));
});

// Resource files
gulp.task('resources', () => {
  src.resources = [
    'package.json',
    'src/content*/**',
    'src/templates*/**'
  ];
  return gulp.src(src.resources)
    .pipe($.changed('build'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
    .pipe($.size({title: 'resources'}));
});


// Bundle
gulp.task('bundle', cb => {
  const config = require('./webpack.config.js');
  const bundler = webpack(config);
  const verbose = !!argv.verbose;
  let bundlerRunCount = 0;

  function bundle(err, stats) {
    if (err) {
      throw new $.util.PluginError('webpack', err);
    }

    if (++bundlerRunCount === (watch ? config.length : 1)) {
      return cb();
    }
  }

  if (watch) {
    bundler.watch(200, bundle);
  } else {
    bundler.run(bundle);
  }
});

// Build the app from source code
gulp.task('build', ['clean'], cb => {
  runSequence(['assets', 'resources'], ['bundle'], cb);
});
```

### EDIT:

The final app.js is minified and I am using `DedupePlugin`, `UglifyJsPlugin`, and `AggressiveMergingPlugin` as well.
Here is the the relevant (I hope) part of my webpack.config

```
const DEBUG = !argv.release;

const appConfig = merge({}, config, {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: './build/public',
    filename: 'app.js'
  },
  node: {
    fs: 'empty'
  },
  devtool: DEBUG ? 'eval-cheap-module-source-map' : false,
  plugins: config.plugins.concat([
    new DefinePlugin(merge(GLOBALS, {
      '__SERVER__': false
    }))
  ].concat(DEBUG ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin()
  ])
  )
});
```

Comment: How big do you think it should be?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. Is this a "normal" size?

Comment: A "normal" size for what kind of app? Is your bundle really minified? Looks like you are only reading the "verbose" argument and not handing the --release flag to the webpack call.

Comment: Yes it is minified. The `--release` flag gets evaluated in the webpack.config. I added this to my question.

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer "what kind of application". The app is based on react and react-redux. I'm talking about this page http://www.wg-cast.de/

Comment: What loaders are you using? Are you extracting CSS or using the style loader to package them with the JS and have it inserted in a style tag? Assets like images can be inlined with certain loaders which can greatly increase build size (especially if you aren't [code splitting](http://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html)). As @ajaegle mentioned it's also hard to approximate your build size without knowing dependencies and project size...

Comment: Another consideration might be ensuring `NODE_ENV=production` is set correctly. In some libraries such as React this will allow the minifier to strip out a lot of unused code from the production build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with Gulp but I know seeing my initial [Webpack](http://webpack.github.io/docs/) build sizes, especially the dev-server outputs, coming from Grunt were pretty intimidating...

#### Solutions

1. Check your loaders, see what assets/data/code are being inlined with your javascript
2. Double check the packages you are `import`ing. Maybe some packages you've installed are larger than you expected. (React by itself is ~150mb minified)
3. See what modules are showing up in your build. If you run the dev-server you should see a whole list. Maybe some are being duplicated or things are included that you didn't intend to add, such as dev packages.
4. See the [code splitting](http://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html) docs and try creating some child bundles (I like the [promise-loader](https://github.com/gaearon/promise-loader) personally) but make sure you also use the [CommonsChunkPlugin](http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin) to deduplicate shared dependencies.
5. Check out [tree shaking](http://www.2ality.com/2015/12/webpack-tree-shaking.html) with Webpack v2

#### Ideas

Webpack is amazing but takes a bit more getting used than many other front-end build tools. I *would highly recommend* trying Webpack by itself on some smaller projects to start instead of mixed in with other tools. I'd be surprised if there was something you were doing with Gulp that you couldn't do with Webpack and you'd save yourself the headache of making two build tools work together.

Hope this helps... I would also check out [Pete Hunt's Webpack HowTo](https://github.com/petehunt/webpack-howto) and [Christian Alfoni's React-Webpack Cookbook](https://github.com/christianalfoni/react-webpack-cookbook) if you are using React.

#### Similar Questions

- [Webpack creating large file with small project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31040379/webpack-creating-large-file-with-small-project)
- [Does webpack make projects bigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34511996/does-webpack-make-projects-bigger)

#### Update

Definitely look into the `NODE_ENV=production` as @djskinner mentioned above to make sure the npm react package is aware that you're doing a production build.